# Maven Dynamic Web Project: My war is deployed with the version in its name. How to change it?

Tags: maven, war

For some reason, my war is deployed as name-version.war

**Before you mark this as duplicate or even downvote me**, I tried all solutions I could find online, but non works. So far, I've tried:

- The finalName tag in the POM
- The maven-war-plugin with its property warName
- Editing org.eclipse.wst.common.component and changing deploy-name to my name

As a result, the url opened by eclipse after "run on server" does not work:

**Should be:**
http://localhost:8080/kest/dbtest.xhtml

**Actual url that works:**
http://localhost:8080/kest-1.0/dbtest.xhtml

This is driving me insane.

What am i doing wrong ?

Here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>kest</name>
    <build>
    <finalName>kest</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Primefaces Version 6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <groupId>my.package.kest</groupId>
    <artifactId>kest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</project>
```

My Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>kest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It is a good idea to have the version in the filename. That's not your problem. Your server is taking its `context` from the filename -- that's the problem. You're maybe missing a web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added -clean to eclipse.ini and cleaned & rebuilt everything, now it works (even without  or .

Maybe this could be helpful to others...

Answer (score 1):

I might seem silly and I don't know if this will work. 
I just moved the group id, artifact id and version to the top before final name declaration.

Please try the below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
   <groupId>my.package.kest</groupId>
    <artifactId>kest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>kest</name>
    <build>
    <finalName>kest</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Primefaces Version 6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

If final name doesn't work, plz use the below and try for the same xml as above.
In the maven-war-plugin, in build, please change

```
<warName> ${artifactId} </warName>
```

Ex:

```
<warName> kest </warName>
```

Replace:

```
        <build>
       ..........                       
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warName>kest</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     .............
   <build>
```

Comment: I already have that, in my first post I listed the solutions I already tried :'(

Comment: Can you please mention which server are you using in Eclipse ?

Comment: I am using WildFly 10

Comment: I have edited my answer. I'm not sure if it will work . Please try.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it did not change. However, I just answered my own own question.